# Make an index column based on FID?

Tags: python, arcpy

I have difficulty copying the `FID` column known as `OBJECTID` to another column.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("file.shp", "index_field", "OBJECTID")
```

if this run it gives a window that says it can't copy the content. 'The calculated value is invalid for the row with ObjectID = 1'. What is the problem?

it gives this error for any column not just FID.

Comment: FID is a phantom column. It cannot be calculated because it represents the physical record number (zero-based), which cannot be changed.

Comment: How to make a similar column then.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question, though I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: Is your layer loaded into ArcMap really called "file.shp"?

Comment: No its just a shapefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would doublecheck that index_field is a integer field and that the objectid field is actually named OBJECTID (not FID).

You can try code below in the [python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm). It should work whatever name the OID column has. If you get an error something else is wrong.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\folder\file.shp' #Change to match your shapefile

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,["index_field","OID@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

(I cant get calculate field with VB to work when i try on a shapefile to calculate a field as the value of FID. Switching to Python parser works though:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Buildings","Indexfield","int(!FID!)","PYTHON")
```

)

Comment: No error this time but it didn't populate the field at all.

Comment: I Think your shapefile is broken. Try making a copy using Copy Features, maybe the copy will be ok. Or: [How To: Recover a corrupt shapefile](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007161)

Comment: Nice! Your calculate field should also work then.

Comment: It returns this window again if I try the CalculateField_management.Any idea?

Comment: I cant get calculate field to work on one of my shapefiles either, using FID field. I dont know why. It works with the updatecursor though.

Comment: I tried with other fields with the same data type and it gives this window all the time.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a way using field calculator but with python parser

Comment: Very good. Do you know what is going on with the window in the other script as the question?Does it have to use Python parser?